# Laravel 4 controller named routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I have a lot of routes defined as:

```
Route::controller('...', '...')
```

Lot of those use the same trait which provides extra routes which are shared across several containers. Is there a way to programatically assign route name based on controller name so that binding happens automatically inside controller (or anywhere else) without me needing to specify explicitly route name?

For example: routes `/user` and `/content` use trait which has `getIndex()` method. Now I have to go to first route and say:

```
'getIndex' => 'user.index'
```

and second one:

```
'getIndex' => 'content.index'
```

If I decide on different naming convention in the process, I will have a really hard time refactoring this.

Comment: you can use [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) feature of Laravel

Comment: That is not an option as I have far more functionalities than resource controller covers

Comment: There's [Laravel Collective's Annotation package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/annotations), but it's only available for Laravel 5. Maybe there is a similar project for L4.